# unfamiliar html/react tag row- , col-

Tags: html, reactjs

I was browsing through the source code of a moderately popular repo, and not sure what are the following tags.

see https://github.com/pusher/react-slack-clone/blob/master/src/index.js#L243

```
 <row->
              <col->
   ....
              </col->
</row->
```

why `-` after the html tags? and how is it an acceptable tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely an error in the source code which has gone unnoticed (possibly by using search & replace?). React accepts element names which end on a `-` character and it gets rendered to the DOM via `document.createElement()` as any other element (for a simple example see here: https://jsfiddle.net/nso3gjpw/ ). Since browsers are very forgiving in case of weird html, it just renders the element as an unknown custom element which behaves roughly like a span element. The `row-` and `col-` elements are also styled (https://github.com/pusher/react-slack-clone/blob/master/src/index.css#L73).

In the Blink rendering engine source code the following definition for tag names is given (https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-CombiningChar):

```
// DOM Level 2 says (letters added):
//
// a) Name start characters must have one of the categories Ll, Lu, Lo, Lt, Nl.
// b) Name characters other than Name-start characters must have one of the categories Mc, Me, Mn, Lm, or Nd.
// c) Characters in the compatibility area (i.e. with character code greater than #xF900 and less than #xFFFE) are not allowed in XML names.
// d) Characters which have a font or compatibility decomposition (i.e. those with a "compatibility formatting tag" in field 5 of the database -- marked by field 5 beginning with a "<") are not allowed.
// e) The following characters are treated as name-start characters rather than name characters, because the property file classifies them as Alphabetic: [#x02BB-#x02C1], #x0559, #x06E5, #x06E6.
// f) Characters #x20DD-#x20E0 are excluded (in accordance with Unicode, section 5.14).
// g) Character #x00B7 is classified as an extender, because the property list so identifies it.
// h) Character #x0387 is added as a name character, because #x00B7 is its canonical equivalent.
// i) Characters ':' and '_' are allowed as name-start characters.
// j) Characters '-' and '.' are allowed as name characters.
//
// It also contains complete tables. If we decide it's better, we could include those instead of the following code.
```

Especially important here is rule `j) Characters '-' and '.' are allowed as name characters.`

Comment: [This commit](https://github.com/pusher/react-slack-clone/commit/d5fa05aa75d4e96834a8a09cce2f3390515eaf89) makes it hard for me to believe that the tag was added in error. Additionally, I'd imagine that these tags would have been noticed and fixed since the elements and their accompanying styles have been moved around a few times since their initial commit.

Comment: @JosiahNunemaker you are completely right, I think they got introduced in [this commit](https://github.com/pusher/react-slack-clone/commit/d5fa05aa75d4e96834a8a09cce2f3390515eaf89). Maybe the author intended to use [col elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/col) for some reason which React [refuses to render](https://jsfiddle.net/n8fdaoL4/) with child elements and `col-` elements were the easiest way out.

Comment: Good find! That hadn't even crossed my mind. Definitely an interesting workaround though.

Answer (score 3):

They are [custom elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/html53/semantics-scripting.html#custom-elements-core-concepts). In regards to the tag's validity, you may have noticed that it is not defined anywhere in the code. As per step 5 of the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom41/#concept-create-element), it is valid, and has a namespace of `Element`.

For a higher-level overview of custom elements, take a look at the [MDN tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements) on using custom elements.

**An additional note:** These tags could be replaced by regular `<div>` tags with classes, and the functionality would be no different.